# Set Commerce Product Price via Rules

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

As this is the first time using rules for me, maybe I am doing something wrong. I want to set the product price to 0 if no price is set. What I am doing so far is this:

Event is "before saving a commerce product"
Condition is "Data value is empty"
Action is "Set a data value"

But there is just nothing happening and I still get an "no price set error" when I try to save a product without a price. Anyone knows how to do it right?

Comment: Use the "When calculating a product's sell price" event instead

Comment: More info: https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/sell-price-calculation

Comment: I changed to "when calculating..." but I still get the error that the price is not set.

Comment: Price fields are required... unless you've changed that. So you're going to get a Form API error.